# Open chrome in new tab rather than new windows via powershell start-process

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, cmd

```
start-process "chrome.exe" '--profile-directory="Default"'
```

When I run this command few times, it opens my default-profile chrome in separate windows. What can I do, to open new tabs, when my default-profile chrome is already opened?

Comment: I doubt if `Start-Process` is going to get you there. You will probably have to do something with the existing Chrome process.

Comment: What do you want to open a new tab of? Presumably you want to open a specific page? In which case you can just take advantage of default browser behaviour using something like:
`Start-Process -FilePath "http://google.com"`

Comment: I want to debug tests via karma in chrome `http://localhost:9876/debug.html` but I'm quite annoyed with popping up chrome windows all the time. It could be great to refresh one opened tab when running tests. I thought that I'd try to run chrom via `.sh` file somehow to get that point

Answer (score 6):

This will open a Tab instead of a new window for me:

```
start-process "chrome.exe" "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",'--profile-directory="Default"'
```

However, if you only want to refresh a page (like you said in the comments), you could also use a little WindowsScript inside of Powershell like this:

```
#  * Get a WindowsScript Shell
$WindowsScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

#  * Check if Chrome is running and activate it
if ($WindowsScriptShell.AppActivate('Chrome')) {

    # * Take a nap to give Windows time to focus Chrome
    Sleep 2 

    # * Refresh the page by sending the F5 Key
    $WindowsScriptShell.SendKeys('{F5}')
}

# * If Chrome isn't there, tell us
Else {
    Write-Output "Chrome is not started!"
}
```

Does that come close?

With VBScript you could also use the `CTRL+<Number>` Combination to switch to a specific tab before refreshing. So you'd have to add
`$vbscriptShell.SendKeys('^2')` before the F5 key. I also tried opening a new tab by using `CTRL+T` ('^T' in VBScript), but that opens a new window and then a new tab for some reason...

Comment: i tried `$WindowsScriptShell.SendKeys('^1'); Sleep 2; $WindowsScriptShell.SendKeys('{F5}')` and it seems to be ok but it's quite tricky and I would have to have my testing tab as a first tab all the time, IE is more controllable via powershell but... :) finally I run tests in the background with `PhantomJS`, print reports in cmd and added npm script to run chrome html reports when needed, anyways thanks for help