# How do I adapt this Internet Explorer script to Chrome

Tags: powershell

I have this script to open some websites in Internet Explorer and I also want it on Chrome but dont know how to adapt it beacuse of the -ComObject

```
$navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000;
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com");
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.navigate2("http://website.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
$IE.Visible = $true
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open chrome in new tab rather than new windows via powershell start-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762170/open-chrome-in-new-tab-rather-than-new-windows-via-powershell-start-process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "www.google.com"
```

You can start a process by name and even pass it a parameter ( URL ) like the above

Comment: I knew this option, but for some reason I thought that it will open every website on a different windows. It seems that I was wrong. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use selenium and do something like this:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Automation\Selenium\Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Automation\Selenium\ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Automation\Selenium\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Automation\Selenium\WebDriver.Support.dll"

$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")
$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")
$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/")

$driver.Quit();
```

For getting the dlls you could do the following:

On your desktop, load Visual Studio and add the following Nuget packages.

```
Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium
Selenium.WebDriver
Selenium.Support
Selenium.RC
Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver
```

Go to the nuget package folders and copy the following dlls and exe out into a folder named `C:\Automation\Selenium`:

- Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll
- ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll
- WebDriver.dll
- WebDriver.Support.dll
- chromedriver.exe